# Angular DataTable bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

I am trying to implement a dataTable.net with bootstrap in a Angular app, but the style is a little bit of like in the image below.
I am using the a pre-built one that I got the code from: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 but even so the appearance is different.

In angular.json I have this:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables.js"
        ]
```

And anlso trying to aply css to change the colors of the buttons.

[Picture problem link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkgcx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing this in the **angular.json** file

Before:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/assets/icons/fontawesome/css/all.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables.js"
        ]
```

After:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/assets/icons/fontawesome/css/all.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Download CDNs of Javascript

[image]

and CSS library files
[image]

from this site [DataTables Bootstrap 4](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) and add them to your project.
That's work for me !!